# firebase deploy hosting from remote (google storage)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-hosting

I have a single page application which I want to host in different gcp projects, i.e. different firebase projects.

The deployment should be done continuously to my firebase hosting, I want to seperate Continuous Build and Continuous Deployment steps and therefore **I don't want to deploy from my local machine** to all my firebase projects manually.

### My question is:

**Is there any best practice around for deploying to a firebase hosting project when I don't want to deploy from my local machine?**

---

In my naive way, I am going to setup the following:

I need to build a zip file that contains all the static html and js files plus my firebase.json and .firebaserc file which I upload to my storage bucket.
With those files the `firebase` CLI tool is able to execute `firebase deploy --only hosting:mytarget`. A google cloud builder could run this command on a git push (from github.com for example) that knows about all my gcp projects I want to deploy the single page app to...

However this is a lot of work and maybe there is a nicer solution for this.
I tried to put a gs:// link directly to the firebase.json hosting/public section, however firebase CLI does not recognize this (it needs a local folder) :-(

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "mySPAApp",
      "public" : "gs://mystorage-containing-files-for-hosting/",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "apps/myapp/**",
          "destination": "myapp/index.html"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

My guts feelings say that there must be an easier way, maybe even with `gcloud` CLI that just deploys a bunch of files to firebase hosting.
Internally in firebase the functionality should be implemented similarly to this, because in the firebase console the user can simply rollback to a previous version of the hosted application, however there seems to be no documentation about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that there is an official REST API for firebase hosting which is a bit cumbersome to use.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions/create
The format of the configuration is different to what is provided normally in firestore.json and the files needed to be uploaded in a state-machine manner in a Version before a Release is created.

Still, not a solution to opt for in my opinion.

Comment: And it is in beta for the last three years. :)